# Writing to Windows Azure Web Sites file system when using multiple Instances

Tags: iis, load-balancing, azure

Let's say I have a Windows Azure Web Site instance which I deploy a simple app like Ghost Blog.

Will a write to one instance be seen by the other instances? Say I upload an image, or write a post to a blog that is using the basic sqlite database.

Or, must I give up on writing to the file system when using multiple instances, and scale *up* rather than *out* in order to be able to write to the file system from multiple instances?

Comment: Aaron, what did you found about this? Did you tried using the Standard tier with multiple VM instances? I have experience with web roles and when using them you must avoid using the file system as a permanent storage. I'm pretty sure that happens the same with an Azure Web Site running in multiple VMs, but I didn't get the chance to confirm it yet.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for an answer to the same question.

This stackoverflow thread sums it up nicely in the thread:

[Can I write to file system on azure web site?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12964129/can-i-write-to-file-system-on-azure-web-site)

Note: It's been a couple of years since that post so it is entirely possible the information in the thread is outdated in some small way (MS has evolved the platform tremendously in that time), but as far as I've been able to tell from playing with it, the answers hold.

Comment: In the future, flag the question as a potential duplicate and provide the link to the stackoverflow question that you believe to be the same.